# Dividing pairs of data frame rows by common names

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like that:

```
         1   2
a_value  2   8
a_ref    4   2
b_value  6  10
b_ref    3  15
c_value  7   3
```

note that some indices are pairs of `name_value` and `name_ref` and others are not

I want to find those pairs, and for each pair get four rows in my new dataframe: `name_value`, `name_ref`, `name_ref/name_value`, `name_value/name_ref` so my output dataframe looks like this:

```
                 1       2
a_value        2.0   8.000
a_ref          4.0   2.000
a_value/a_ref  0.5   4.000
a_ref/a_value  2.0   0.250
b_value        6.0  10.000
b_ref          3.0  15.000
b_value/b_ref  2.0   0.666
b_ref/b_value  0.5   1.500
```

I currently do it by iterating over the indices looking for ones that end with `value` and then trying to find the matching `ref`, but knowing pandas, it seems that there should be an easier way, maybe using groupby somehow. So.. is there?

Comment: What is `name_value` and `name_ref`?

Comment: the indices (the word `name` is a place holder, so one pait for example is the row with index `a_value` and the one with index `a_ref`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works. First, lets find the common keys:

```
import numpy as np
keys = np.intersect1d(df.index.str.extract("(.+)_value").dropna(),
                      df.index.str.extract("(.+)_ref").dropna())
#array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)
```

Next, select the matching refs and values:

```
refs   = df.loc[keys + "_ref"]
values = df.loc[keys  +"_value"]
```

Make a copy of each dataframe and assign them the keys as indexes:

```
values1 = values.copy()
values1.index = keys
refs1 = refs.copy()
refs1.index = keys
```

Perform the division and update the indexes once again:

```
ratios = values1 / refs1
ratios.index += "_value" + "/" + ratios.index + "_ref"
ratios1 = refs1 / values1
ratios1.index += "_ref" + "/" + ratios1.index + "_value"
```

Put everything together and sort:

```
pd.concat([refs, values, ratios, ratios1]).sort_index()
#                 1          2
#a_ref          4.0   2.000000
#a_ref/a_value  2.0   0.250000
#a_value        2.0   8.000000
#a_value/a_ref  0.5   4.000000
#b_ref          3.0  15.000000
#b_ref/b_value  0.5   1.500000
#b_value        6.0  10.000000
#b_value/b_ref  2.0   0.666667
```

Comment: dont use `ix`, because deprecated. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated :)

Comment: looks good, thanks. I'll just wait a bit to see if there is a more elegant solution and mark your solution if not. Just note the `ix` has been deprecated, so it will be better to use `loc`